# including files from different directories

Tags: php, filepath

So I set up my include files, such as `header.php`, `nav.php`, and `footer.php` in a `/inc` folder.

Then I include the files in my pages. But if I have another folder, for example `wiki` where i'd like to include those files onto the pages of wiki, the file paths for the includes break.

Example: I have included this in a page from the `wiki` directory.

```
<?php include_once('../inc/header.php'); ?>
```

I have two other includes in the header.php file, but since I'm including them in a different directory, both includes break, unless I go and append a `../` in the include path.

I'm wondering what is the best way to include files within different directories and not having to go back and fix the path?

Answer (score 3):

Create constants using `realpath` in the initial file and then reference them using easy to read and manage but now absolute paths.

You can see an example here:

[How can I get the "application root" of my URL from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311983/how-can-i-get-the-application-root-of-my-url-from-php)

I'd also suggest testing for the constant definition before defining.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution? Use absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in directories of the same level, the relative pathes (with ../) will be the same. If you have one within another, you will need to have the ../ on the beginning of the one in the sub-directory. The only way around changing the paths is to create a link as a sub-directory representing the main directory, although this can have dangerous consequences relating to recursive processes.

btw, include_once means that this operation is "optional", meaning the program will continue to execute. If you require the files included, use require_once, and the program will break if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Include them like this

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'inc'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'header.php');
```

This could work!

Answer (score 0):

I like using this method:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); // Defined on the index or in the bootstrap
include(ROOT_DIR . 'subfolder/fileName.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP's native set_include_path to add an include folder you can then include files just by their name.

```
<?php
/**
 * The path to your /inc/ folder.
 */
$path = '/absolute/path/to/inc/';

/**
 * get_include_path retrieve's the current include path. 
 * It's a bad idea to over write the entire include path
 * The PATH_SEPARATOR constant is set per operating system
 */
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

/**
 * You can now include any files in /inc/ from any directory with no path
 */
include_once('header.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the `DocumentRoot` of your webserver, e.g. Apache. Then you can take that as a stable datum and map from there as that won't vary.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/header.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to do str_replace("\\","/",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) when running on IIS if that helps.